# Form that is HMTL5 Won't Validate

Tags: javascript, css, html, validation

The form will goto validate but then skips it and just goes directly to the end result.

http://jsbin.com/danimemu/3/edit

Comment: I don't understand your question, nor does your code make it easy to understand what might be a problem. Please expand your question.

Comment: Typically in a HTML5 form when you have the required attribute it does not allow a null field to pass data through and stops the user from pressing submit and proceeding. But I am using two submit button types on this form. So when I press either it skips checking for blank data and just goes to the end result which is a php script that runs.

Comment: What I am asking is I do not understand why this is happening. Why it is letting the user proceed when the fields are blank even though I have the required attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the [submission algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), it looks like your problem is that you are handling the `onclick` event of the buttons, rather than handling the `onsubmit` event of the `<form>`. In step 4 of the algorithm, it is stated

> If the submitted from submit() method flag is not set, and the submitter element's no-validate state is false, then interactively validate the constraints of form...

This suggests to me that since you are explicitly calling the `form.submit()` function, you are telling the HTML processor that you have done all the validation that is needed and the form should be submitted. (Sadly, I wasn't able to find a nice simple blog post walking through an explanation or example.) You need to remove the `onclick` handlers of the buttons and let the form submit normally, which will trigger the validation. You can add the `formaction` HTML5 attribute to your buttons to submit to a different URL for each button without using JavaScript.

Comment: AH WOW that formaction attribute is what I've been missing all day! Thank you! AMAZING SOLUTION!